# requested recovery stop point is before consistent recovery point

Tags: postgresql, restore

I am getting below error while restoring Postgres instance to a point in time.

```
FATAL:  requested recovery stop point is before consistent recovery point
```

below is my recovery.conf content

```
restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/pgsql/pg_log_archive/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = '2018-04-17 10:56:27'
recovery_target_inclusive = false
```

I want to restore postgreSQL instance to a specified time.What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with an earlier base backup than the one you are currently starting from.  PostgreSQL can only recover forward, not backward.

Comment: I also reached on the same conclusion after some googling.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there is timezone mismatch between barman and postgres db.
I have to convert the time to GMT then the restore and db start is a success.